# How to make Node.JS function that calls solidity withdraw function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't get JS properly to call my solidity function withdraw funds. I have got solidity:

```js
function withdrawFunds() public {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner");
    (bool success, ) = payable(owner).call {
        value: address(this).balance
    }("");
    require(success);
}
```

And it works, but I cant figure out how to properly call it in JS.

So far I have this in JS:

```js
const withdrawFunds = async () => {
    try {
        await Contractoftickets.methods.withdrawFunds().call({
            from: address,
        })
        setSuccessMsg(`Funds withdrawn!`)
    }
}
```

It executes but it currently does not withdraw funds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With ethers.js you can do it like this:

```
const withdrawFunds = async () => {
   try {
      const Contractoftickets = ethers.getContract(contractAddress, contractInterfaceOrABI)
      await Contractoftickets.withdrawFunds()
      setSuccessMsg(`Funds withdrawn!`)
  }
}
```

I'll recommend you to go through ethers docs for more details. A simple note, *you've to install ethers and connect your wallet with it before using it like above*.

Comment: Thank you, managed to solve it myself by just replacing call with send, but yeah I should have provided more information about other parts of my code, because I had already declared ethers.getContract part in other part of file.